# Windows device's magnetometer calibration

Tags: .net, uwp, windows-7, windows-8, sensors

How to calibrate device's magnetometer in my application? Need I just spin the tablet around or should I call some API methods? Or I have to write alghoritm itself? It depends on concrete sensor? Is it possible via "Sensor and Location Platform"?

How to know that calibration is needed, by "HeadingAccuracy" property? What if sensor does not have such value?

I've tried to find all the answers but there is only 
scraps of information in the internet.

Thanks for any explanations.

Comment: Are you developing [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) app? You added three different platform tags.

Comment: No, I'm developing .NET 4 app, but I would want to know about it on at least one any platform